# How to get Row Index of vaadin-grid

Tags: vaadin, polymer-2.x, vaadin-grid

I am trying to loop through `vaadin-grid` rows to set row styles, however, am having trouble selecting a row.

```
<vaadin-grid id="grid" items="[[data]]">
  <vaadin-grid-column>
    <template class="header">
      <vaadin-grid-sorter path="noLine">
        <h1>Line No.</h1>
      </vaadin-grid-sorter>
    </template>
    <template>
      <p>[[item.noLine]]</p>
    </template>
</vaadin-grid-column>
```

...

```
_selectRow() {
  // Programmatically select row
}
```

I can select the row data with `this.$.grid.items[arrayIndex]`...

**How can I select a row to set the row styling?**

Comment: One option to style the contents of the grid, depending on the item rendered, is to use inline style bindings. For example `<p style$='color: {{item.color}}'>[[item.noLine]]<p>`.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Gilberto's suggestion:

```
<vaadin-grid-column>
   <template class="header">
     <vaadin-grid-sorter path="qty">
       <h3>Qty</h3>
       </vaadin-grid-sorter>
    </template>
  <template>
    <p style$="color: [[setCellStyle(item.qty item.qtyOther]]</p>
  </template>
</vaadin-grid-column>
```

...

```
setCellStyle(qty, qtyOther) {
  if(qty <= qtyOrder) return 'black'
  else return 'orangered'
}
```